# Adding a single-custom-template to menu-items created in with taxononies, category and subcategory

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi I have question regarding assigning a single-meny-template.php to a menu-items, created under taxonomies.

I have created a single-meny-template.php in my templates folder on the root of my theme.
and I want to assign this template to the taxonomies/ cats/ subscats/ subcatsitem.

I am able to assign this template to the post in meny, however i am getting a blank page loading nothing.
the links build like i want structure. domein.xxx/taxonomy-slug/cat/sub-cat/item
Can some one please help? Why my custom-post-type is not showing.
I can see it is applied to psk/meny instead of full link.

```
<?php
    /*
Template Name: Single Meny Template
Template Post Type: meny 
*/

get_template_part('templates/main-header-template');

while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_title('<h1>', '</h1>');
    the_content();
endwhile;

get_footer();

?>
```

this is my functions.php code:

```
<?php
error_log('Creating sub-category');

add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

// Register Custom Taxonomy for Menu Categories
function psk_meny_register_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Menu Categories', 'taxonomy general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Menu Category', 'taxonomy singular name'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Menu Categories'),
        'all_items' => __('All Menu Categories'),
        'parent_item' => __('Parent Menu Category'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Menu Category:'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Menu Category'),
        'update_item' => __('Update Menu Category'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Menu Category'),
        'new_item_name' => __('New Menu Category Name'),
        'menu_name' => __('Menu Categories'),
        'order_number' => __('Order Number'), // Added numeric label
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'meny'),
    );

    register_taxonomy('psk_meny_categories', array('meny'), $args);
}
add_action('init', 'psk_meny_register_taxonomy');

function psk_register_meny_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Meny Items',
        'singular_name' => 'Menu Item',
        'add_new' => 'Add New Item',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Menu Item',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Menu Item',
        'new_item' => 'New Menu Item',
        'view_item' => 'View Menu Item',
        'search_items' => 'Search Menu Items',
        'not_found' => 'No menu products found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No menu products found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Menu Items',
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'meny',
            'with_front' => false,
        ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-list-view',
        'taxonomies' => array('psk_meny_categories'),
    );

    register_post_type('meny', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'psk_register_meny_post_type');

function custom_meny_permalink($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {
    if ($post->post_type === 'meny') {
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'psk_meny_categories');

        if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
            $main_cat = '';
            $sub_cat = '';

            // Find the main category and sub-category
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                if ($term->parent === 0) {
                    $main_cat = $term->slug;
                } else {
                    $sub_cat = $term->slug;
                }
            }

            // If there's a sub-category, include it in the permalink
            $sub_cat_part = $sub_cat ? "{$sub_cat}/" : '';

            // Construct the final permalink
            $post_link = home_url("meny/{$main_cat}/{$sub_cat_part}{$post->post_name}/");
        }
    }

    return $post_link;
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_meny_permalink', 10, 4);


function add_template_to_dropdown($post_templates, $wp_theme, $post, $post_type) {
    if ($post_type === 'meny') {
        $post_templates['single-meny-template.php'] = __('Single Meny Template');
    }

    return $post_templates;
}
add_filter('theme_single_template', 'add_template_to_dropdown', 10, 4);



function custom_template_for_meny_items($template) {
    global $post;

    // Check if we have a valid post object
    if (is_a($post, 'WP_Post') && $post->post_type === 'meny') {
        // Include the custom template if it exists in the 'template' folder
        get_template_part('template/single-meny-template');

        // Return an empty template string
        return '';
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'custom_template_for_meny_items');

?>
```